# Equivalence relation $a\sim b$ iff $a=10^kb$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

Consider the relation on the set of all real numbers $\mathbb R$, defined by $a\sim b$ if, and only if, there exists an integer $k$ so that $a = 10^k b$. Prove or disprove: this is an equivalence relation.

I have no idea what it's talking about, anyone understand this ?!

Comment: This has literally nothing to do with linear algebra.  Please use relevant tags and titles for the question.

Comment: Do you understand what is an equivalence relation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is asking you to prove that a relation, $\sim$, is an equivalence relation.  A binary relation is technically a subset of the cartesian product of a set on itself.  Although the words may seem foreign, you've been using relations your whole life.  Think of it as a way of "comparing" things.  For example, $5<7$, we say that $5$ is "less than" $7$, and with respect to the relation "$<$" we would say that $5$ is related to $7$.

(*Note that we don't require under normal circumstances that it be symmetric.  We can have $5<7$ but $7\not <5$*)

The specific relation given to us in this problem is $a\sim b$ iff there exists some integer $k$ such that $a=10^k b$.  For example, $37\sim 3700$ since $37 = 10^{-2}\cdot 3700$.  Also $890001\sim 890.001$ since $890001=890.001\cdot 10^3$.

---

To prove something is an equivalence relation you must show the following three things:

- Reflexivity: Every element is related to itself.
- Symmetry: If $a\sim b$ then it must also be that $b\sim a$
- Transitivity: If $a\sim b$ and $b\sim c$ then it must also be that $a\sim c$

---

Reflexivity:  Suppose $a\in\mathbb{R}$.  Does there happen to be an integer $k$ such that $a=10^k a$?

---

Symmetry:  Suppose that $a\sim b$.  So, that means that $a=10^k b$ for some integer $k$.  Does there happen to be a good choice for $l$ so that $b=10^l a$?

---

Transitivity:  Suppose that $a\sim b$ and $b\sim c$.  So that means there is some integer $k$ and $l$ such that $a=10^k b$ and $b=10^l c$.  Does there happen to be a good choice for $m$ that makes it so that $a=10^m c$?